# Stop clockwork, started from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks

How can I stop clockwork, which started by

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec clockwork config/schedule.rb &
```

We are using it without God, Monit or anything else

Comment: Find the process id and kill it. On a unix terminal  `ps -ef | grep clockwork`

Answer (score 1):

since version 0.5.2 you can call

`clockworkd -c [your .rb file] start|stop|restart`